# How to store original date/time without timezone calculation to MongoDb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, date, timezone

I'm getting a list of some events in a different locations from providers  with events date/time (events are in different timezones, so the dates/time are always local). I need to save it to the mongodb as I got them, but it looks like Mongo is converting it using my local timezone, so instead of event that starts at 20:00 i got 18:00 saved in the database.

I'm using java spring boot app and when I try to filter results, if i select events after 19:00, my event is not in a list, but it should be there. I would like to store those dates without calculating timezone. Is there any way to configure mongo not to do the calculation? I'm using mongodb driver version 3.9.0.

Update (time field definition):

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Field("time")
private LocalDateTime time;
```

Update 2:
I played with shell and when I insert something like:

```
var mydate2 = ISODate();
db.test.insertOne( { iso: mydate2 } );
```

the result is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5173dc6240209d9377677a"), "iso" : ISODate("2019-08-12T14:12:42.762Z") }
```

but when I insert Date instead:

```
var mydate2 = Date();
db.test.insertOne( { iso: mydate2 } );
```

the result is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d51741b6240209d9377677b"), "iso" : "Mon Aug 12 2019 16:13:42 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Standard Time)" }
```

, so the correct one. 
Can I somehow say from Spring document definition that I want to use Date? Should I use ZonedDateTime instead of LocalDateTime?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using `ISODate`?

Comment: Yes, ISODate. Using also mongobee. It looks like mongo is doing this when converting LocalDateTime to Date before saving. Maybe I shouldnt use LocalDateTime in the mongo document definition?

Comment: You should use UTC/GMT/Zulu, not local.

Comment: where, how? For field in document definition? I will update question with my current time field definition in the document...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this using ZonedDateTime instead of LocalDateTime:
In the spring data mongo document definition

```
@Field("eventTime")
private ZonedDateTime eventTime;
```

Mongo doesnt have its own converter for ZonedDateTime so I created my own:

```
public class ZonedDateTimeReadConverter implements Converter<Date, ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(Date date) {
        return date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ZonedDateTimeWriteConverter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convert(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        return Date.from(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
    }
}
```

We also need to register it in MongoDbConfig class like:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoDbCommonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ValidatingMongoEventListener validatingMongoEventListener() {
        return new ValidatingMongoEventListener(validator());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        ZonedDateTimeReadConverter zonedDateTimeReadConverter = new ZonedDateTimeReadConverter();
        ZonedDateTimeWriteConverter zonedDateTimeWriteConverter = new ZonedDateTimeWriteConverter();

        return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(zonedDateTimeReadConverter, zonedDateTimeWriteConverter));
    }
}
```

and when I get my events provider, I'm changing its LocalDateTime to ZonedDateTime at UTC zone like:

```
return new Event(providerEvent.getTime().atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")), providerEvent.getName(),...);
```

and now when I got 18:00 from the provider for the event, 18:00 will be saved to the mongodb..

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` here defies the purpose - originally it has TZ, but you store it in Z. When you recover it - the original TZ is lost.
If you always want dates in Z - use `Instant` - this is far less misleading ,and it's supported by default.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any [data type in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) for date and time without time zone or offset.

## ISO 8601

So I suggest you save to values as text in standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS. The `T` separates the date portion from time portion.

Notice how such text is chronological when sorted alphabetically.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020 , 1 , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( ld , lt ) ;
String output = ldt.toString() ;
```

> 2020-01-23T15:30

Parsing.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2020-01-23T15:30:00" ) ;
```

Comment: Cant use Text options because I'm using aggregations and there are limits when using String instead of Iso.

Comment: I would add 'Z' at the end of the string to emphasize that it is UTC: "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS.sssZ". It is part of ISO8601

Comment: @Shloim You missed the main point of the Question: date and time *without* considering zone/offset. So adding the `Z` for UTC is exactly what *not* to do here.

Comment: You are correct. I did miss it. I'm used to a convention where either you store msec/sec since epoch, and then there's actually no timezone info, or you store the time in UTC, and then it is also timezone neutral. The idea of storing the time in yyyymmddHHMMSS format without any timezone information baffles me, since it only introduces complications such as time zone conversion and daylight savings incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try use Instant.

```
Instant i = Instant.now();
ZoneId losAngelesTimeZone = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
System.out.println(i.atZone(chicagoTimeZone));
```

Comment: but I want to avoid playing with timezones. I just wants my date/times saved as is... It cant be so hard? I'm I missing something?

Comment: Normally, I receive datetime in ISO 1861 UTC.
Save it in DB in UTC, and when you show for client to convert to client timezone or application user configuration timezone.

I think you need save 'LocalDateTime' with you need save timezone.

Comment: When I load it back it is converterd back, but  when I do filtering directly with repo this is not calculating offset... so my filtering is not working. I managed to fix it, will provide an answer tomorrow...